# text' is unavailable apis deprecated as of ios 7 and earlier are unavailable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, deprecation-warning

This error keeps popping up. I keep looking everywhere and can't find a solution.

[image]

Comment: just click there for the photo

Comment: the cell has no text property you have to access the label text property

Comment: Questions which depend on screenshots require more work to answer and are generally less useful to other people with the same question as screen shots and images tend to disappear. I suspect you'll see more answers and upvotes if you can avoid depending on images.

Answer (score 3):

When confronted by a question about a method a good place to start is the  [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/text) (for UITableViewCell in this case).

> text  (iOS 3.0)  *Property*
>
> The text of the cell.
>
> **Deprecation Statement** 
>   Use the `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties
>   instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cell.textLabel!.text
```

instead